# Yarn - hadoop doesn't initialize correctly

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I tried to install Hadoop 3.2.1 (single node) in my Ubuntu VM, however the Yarn site doesn't run. I execute jps command and returns this:

```
26984 SecondaryNameNode
24266 Jps
26685 DataNode
26526 NameNode
```

May this error be in the yarn-site.xml?

```xml
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```xml
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```xml
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Is there a good tutorial that explains how to install Hadoop 3.2.1 (single node) in Linux

Comment: Are you trying to install plain Apache Hadoop? Or any specific Hadoop distribution?

Comment: I tried to install hadoop 3.2.1, YARN and map reduce single node in ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for below link for Hadoop installation on single node,

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation